# Does not conform to String protocol SwiftUI Picker View

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple `struct` that I will build upon. Right now it has one field, an Int.

```
struct Card: CustomStringConvertible  {
  let value: Int

  init(value: Int) {
    self.value = value
  }

  var description: String {
    return "\(String(value))"
  }
}
```

If I do this, I get the Card to print it's value

```
let c = Card(value: 1)
print(c)
```

Now if I put an array of Cards in a CardController like this:

```
class CardController: ObservableObject {
  @Published
  var cards: [Card] = [
    Card(value: 1),
    Card(value: 2),
    Card(value: 3)
  ]
```

```
Picker(selection: $selectedCardValue, label: Text("Choose a card")) {
        ForEach(0..<cardController.cards.count) {
          Text(self.cardController.cards[$0])
        }
      }
      Text("You selected \(selectedCardValue)")
```

I'll get the error `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Card' conform to StringProtocol`. I'm not sure why I get this error. If I instead  just change the `cards` to a type of `[String]` and values `["1", "2", "3"]`, the code works fine.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As E.Coms noted, the solution is to use one of the following:

`Text(self.cardController.cards[$0].description)`

`Text(String(describing: self.cardController.cards[$0]))`

Here's an explanation of  *why* you have to do this inside the `Text` initializer, but not `print()`.

---

Look at the two initializers for `Text`:

`init(verbatim content: String)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3065756-init))

`init<S>(_ content: S) where S : StringProtocol` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/3065756-init))

You must pass either a `String` or a `Substring`, the [only two types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol) conforming to `StringProtocol`. In this case, even though your type conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, you are still passing a `Card`.

---

Contrast this with something like the `print` function:

`func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n")` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print))

Notice that the `print` function's arguments are denoted by `Any`, which [is explained as](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html#ID342)

> Any can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

The [print function then converts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print) whatever you passed it to a `String`:

> The textual representation for each item is the same as that obtained by calling String(item).

`String` has an [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3129029-init) which takes a type conforming to `CustomStringConvertible` and returns the `description` property.

---

So the reason you can write `print(Card())` and not `Text(Card()` is because the print function has an intermediate step through `String` that can understand your conformance to `CustomStringConvertible`, but `Text` does not. If `Text` allowed you to pass it any type, it would be both more ambiguous ("What is the text representation of this type?" is not necessarily immediately apparent, as it depends on a hierarchical set of protocols), and more work for the SwiftUI system, which is already doing a lot.

Comment: I really appreciate the thorough explanation. Thank you.

Comment: for some reason .description did not work for me, but String(describing:... did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may miss the `description` by chance.

```
 ForEach(0..<cardController.cards.count) {
    Text(self.cardController.cards[$0].description)
 }
```